# How do I define a generic method in a base class that will use a lambda for different unique property names?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I'm new to using generic classes so I'm not sure my question uses the right terms.  I am creating a project using EF Core.  I have created a bunch of repository classes for each model, but it is getting unwieldy and I am looking at creating a base repository for the common CRUD methods.  I am trying to use generic methods following some examples I have seen online.  But I don't know how to define those methods to use properties which will have a different name in each child class.

So each repository has a method like this:

```
public Contact Select(int contactId)
{
   return _ctx.Contact.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContactId == contactId);
}
```

or

```
public ContactRole Select(int contactRoleId)
{
   return _ctx.ContactRole.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContactRoleId == contactRoleId);
}
```

Following the examples, I created an interface

```
public interface IRepositoryBase<T>
    {
        T Select(int id);        
        void Add(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        IQueryable<T> FindAll();
    }
```

and then an abstract base class like this

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
   public T Select(int id)
   {
      this._context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContactRoleId == id);
   }

   public void Add(T entity)
   {
      this._context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
   }
}
```

I don't know what I am supposed to put in place of the **ContactRoleId** in this function.  I'm sure if all the models used the same field called "Id" it could work, but the database I am using has a different name for the id field of each table.  Also, I left in the Add function, did I do that correctly?

Comment: You need an information that's not available in your abstract class. How do you want to provide it? As part of your concrete class or as function parameter?

Comment: By concrete class you mean ContactRepository : RepositoryBase, right?  How would I do that, or how would I use a function parameter?

Comment: Entity Framework has a [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1.find?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method; I would use that assuming `id` always refers to the primary key.

Comment: So like this?: return this._context.Set<T>().Find(id);

Comment: If you need to define a property somewhere, keep in mind, that while it looks like a function, we're working with expressions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netcore-3.1 - that's the description of a function.